# Is there in AppleScript any way to use "X of every" to get multiple properties of each object to create a record?

Tags: macos, safari, applescript, automation, tabs

It is possible to with the script:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set urls to URL of every tab of every window
end tell
```

when execute, get all urls of every tab of every window (two dimensional list)

```
Result:
 {{"http://domain1", "http://domain2", ...}, {"http://domain3", "http://domain4", ...}, {...}}
```

But is it possible with:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set (urls & name) to URL of every tab of every window
end tell
```

to get a record instead of list:

```
Result:
 {{{url: "http://domain1", name: "domain1 - foo"}, {url: "http://domain2", name: "domain2 - bar2"}, {...}}, {{url: "http://domain3", name: "domain3 - foo3"}, {url: "http://domain4", name: "domain4 - bar4"}, {...}}}
```

Is it possible, or should I use only `repeat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to get a record with a single object specifier, but you can get a list:

```
tell application "Safari"
    {URL, name} of tabs of windows
end tell
-- {{{"http://url1", "title 1"}, {"http://url2", "title 2"}}}
```

For a record, you can use a repeat loop:

```
set r to {}
tell application "Safari"
    repeat with t in tabs of windows
        set end of r to {|url|:URL of t, |name|:name of t}
    end repeat
end tell
r
-- {{|url|:"http://url1", |name|:"title 1"}, {|url|:"http://url2", |name|:"title 2"}}
```

Comment: great! is it possible get all this with `{|safari|: {{|window_1|: {|url|: "http://url1", |name|: "title 1"}, {|url|:"http://url2", |name|:"title 2"}},{|window_2|: {|url|: "http://url3", |name|: "title 3"}, {|url|:"http://url4", |name|:"title 4"}}}}` ? So that I could convert the record to json (e.g. with `JSON Helper`) and still have a safari windows structure? I wrote a script for that all to get a string-based (not record-/list-based, what I would like to have), and it is about 200 lines of code with 3 subroutines and it looks ugly even for myself

Comment: If I test so: `{|safari|: {|window1|: {{|url1|: "http1", |name1|: "title1"},{|url2|: "http2", |name2|: "title2"},{|url3|: "http3", |name3|: "title3"}}}} & {|safari|: {|window2|: {{|url1|: "http1", |name1|: "title1"},{|url2|: "http2", |name2|: "title2"},{|url3|: "http3", |name3|: "title3"}}}}` it returns only: `{safari:{window1:{{url1:"http1", name1:"title1"}, {url2:"http2", name2:"title2"}, {url3:"http3", name3:"title3"}}}}` and not the merged variant, where there is a list of `windows`

Comment: The double curly brackets (e.g. list): `{|safari|: -->{{<-- |window1|: ...` doesn't make any change

Comment: sorry for so many off-topic comments, but I almost solved this to myself: how to set the the key of the record in the runtime? so `set end of w_l to {|window & "_" & window_i :t_l}` ?